# How could I generate 100 grid maps?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have built a `map` that generates `obstacles, start point and endpoint randomly` for pathfinding algorithm. As shown below:

```
import random
import numpy as np

x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(50)]for j in range(50)]
grid = np.array([[0 for i in range(len(x[0]))]for j in range(len(x))])

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        if x[i][j] <= 0.7:
            grid[i][j] = 0
        else:
            grid[i][j] = 1

init = np.random.randint(0, high = 49, size = 2) #Start location 
goal = np.random.randint(0, high = 49, size = 2) #Our goal 

# clear starting and end point of potential obstacles
def clear_grid(grid, x, y):
    if x != 0 and y != 0:
        grid[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2]=0
    elif x == 0 and y != 0:
        grid[x:x+2,y-1:y+2]=0
    elif x != 0 and y == 0:
        grid[x-1:x+2,y:y+2]=0
    elif x ==0 and y == 0:
        grid[x:x+2,y:y+2]=0

clear_grid(grid, init[0], init[1])
clear_grid(grid, goal[0], goal[1])
```

As shown above, this snippet will give me `one environment` (grid map) with `random obstacles`, `start point` and `endpoint`. I need to create `100 environments` (grid maps) and every environment of these 100 gives me random obstacles, start point and endpoint. Could I get any assistance, please?.

Comment: What's stopping you from running this code 100 times?

Comment: @glibdud What do you mean dear?

Comment: I mean what's the actual problem you're running into? If it works once and you need it to work 100 times, run it 100 times in a loop and save the results in a list (or whatever data structure you need).

Comment: @glibdud I need to apply an A star algorithm on every one of the 100 environments. I'm so confused about the looping problem. Could you solve this matter for me dear just the looping problem?.

Comment: You don't need that ```x``` array nor that loop to randomize grid with zeros and ones. Something like this will do it in one pass ```grid = np.array([ [ int(random.uniform(0,1)*2) for i in range(50) ] for j in range(50) ])```. And, with that in mind, you can just do something like this: ```grids = np.array([ [ [ int(random.uniform(0,1)*2) for i in range(50) ] for j in range(50) ] for _ in range(100) ])```

Comment: @accdias Good idea dear. But there is a loop under it for controlling the number of ones that will generate. Now how could I deal with it after deleting X?

Comment: @SH_IQ, I fixed that in my answer. Check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you 100 grids 50x50 with random zeros and ones, taking into consideration your rule (uniform(0, 1) <= .7) to fill in `ones`:

```
from random import uniform
import numpy as np

grids = np.array([[[0 if uniform(0, 1) <= .7 else 1 for i in range(50)] for j in range(50)] for _ in range(100)])
```

The code above replaces the one below and also gives you 100 grids in one pass:

```
import random
import numpy as np

x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(50)]for j in range(50)]
grid = np.array([[0 for i in range(len(x[0]))]for j in range(len(x))])

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        if x[i][j] <= 0.7:
            grid[i][j] = 0
        else:
            grid[i][j] = 1
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from random import uniform
>>> grids = np.array([[[0 if uniform(0, 1) <= .7 else 1 for i in range(50)] for j in range(50)] for _ in range(100)])
>>> grids
array([[[0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0]],

       ...,

       [[1, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
        ...,
        [1, 0, 1, ..., 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 1]]])
>>>
>>> len(grids)
100
>>> len(grids[0])
50
>>> len(grids[0][0])
50
>>>
```

Comment: Yes dear. But what about the loop that under the grid. I use it to control the number of ones. How could I deal with it now?

Answer (score 2):

[`np.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) almost does what you want, apart from the per-grid proportion. I think this is quite nice to read and nearly 10 times faster than nested loops:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[0.7, 0.3], size=(50, 50)) for _ in range(100)])
```

Comment: very nice. Thank you so much dear. What does p=[0.7, 0.3] mean?

Comment: @SH_IQ Those are the probabilities of the items from which the choice is made, in this case `[0, 1]`. It maybe makes more sense to put them right after the choices, so I'll move them.